# Analytics / GTM - Sending Variables to Web Form

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In short I'm trying to send the 'Session Default Channel' variable within a web form.

Is it possible to access Analytics variables on the webpage itself?

Can this be done via the page view trigger or potentially create and event on form submission to populate the field?

We need to do this so the leads can be recorded within a CRM.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. GA processes some variables (specifically, the channel) additionally.

What's possible, however, is duplicating the channel logic in your GTM, determining the channel on the first hit based on query params and referrer, then storing it in the cookie and then using it where you need it. This solution works, but it's improper since it creates tech debt on the GTM side. It's basically a hack.

A proper solution for this would be building a proper datalake and joining your analytics data with the other sources of data like the CRM, backend DB and whatnot. But it's definitely a more expensive solution that wouldn't fit smaller organizations.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly the information I've found elsewhere. I've introduced a method ("I" is doing some heavy lifting here) that stores UTM values in a cookie which I can add to a field. 

This will cover paid search (I'll recommend we use UTM values across the board). Then for everything else I will base it off the referrer value.

Comment: yes, that's a common approach.